# Manage memory differently on train and test time pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Currently I'm writing a segmentation model based on U-net with pytorch and I want to use something similar to inverted residual introduced on mobilenet v2 to improve the model's speed on cpu. [pytorch code for mobile netv2](https://github.com/tonylins/pytorch-mobilenet-v2)

Then I realize that the model uses a lot more memory on train phase and test phase. While the model should use more memory on train phase because all the mid-step tensors(feature maps) are saved and with separable convolution there are more tensors created for each "convolution" operation. 
But on run time, actually only few last step tensors must be saved to be used for skip connection and all the other tensors can be deleted once it's next step is created. The memory efficiency should be the same for u-net with normal convolution and u-net with separable convolution on test phase.

I'm newbee to pytorch so I don't know how to write code that prevents unnecessary memory cost on test time. Since pytorch is binded with python. I guess I can manually delete all the unnecessary tensors in forward function with del. But I guess that if I just delete variables on forward function, it will influence training stage.
Is here more advanced functionality on pytorch that is able to optimize test phase memory usage with a 'network graph'?
I'm also curious if tensorflow deals with those problems automatically since it has a more abstract and complex graph building logic.

Comment: are you using `.eval()` when testing out of curiosity

Comment: Yes and I did the test with no_grad

Answer (score 2):

After reading the official pytorch code for resnet, I realize I shouldn't give all variables a name.aka I shouldn't write:

```
conv1 = self.conv1(x)
conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
```

I should just write:

```
out = self.conv1(x)
out = self.conv2(out)
```

On this way nothing refers to obj corresponds to conv1 after it is used and python is able to clean it.

because there are residual connections between blocks, I need to have one more python variable to refer to the variable: aka

```
out = self.conv1(x)
residual_connect = out
out = self.conv2(out)
out = conv1 + out
```

But on upsampling stage only out is needed. So I deleted residual_connect at the beginning of the decoding stage.

```
del residual_connect
```

It seems like a hack and I'm surprised that it didn't cause problem on training stage. The ram usage for my model is greatly reduced now but I feel here should be a more elegant way to solve the problem.

Comment: May I ask if the "ram" mentioned is used to represent GPU memory or CPU memory? In my mind, "RAM" usually refers to CPU memory. But in this context wouldn't make sense because we are training on GPUs. Also, since gradients are calculated using those feature_map, I assume deleting them is a trade-off between GPU calculation time and GPU memory. Am I right?

Comment: Here ram is GPU memory or CPU memory. I don't think it works as you guessed, or dont make those assumption when you are doing your work. you should use torch.utils.checkpoint to achieve what you believes deleting item can achieve. I just hope deleting tensors is able to make the model release the memory (CPU or GPU) on test time and magically work on train time...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used `torch.no_grad()` during testing, automatically you are asking the Context-manager to disable gradient calculation which results in less memory usage than training. However, I found that the **caching allocator** occupies a lot of memory which can be released after each update to your model during training which saves a lot of memory.

So, you can use the function [torch.cuda.empty_cache()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html?highlight=empty_cache#torch.cuda.empty_cache) and I found it really helpful in my case. Also, reading the [memory management](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#memory-management) can help you to learn other important things about GPU memory management in PyTorch.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but actually I tried this command and it didn't help. After I run the command I tried to print out existing tensors again, I still see a lot of unnecessary feature maps. And I'm running model on cpu. I did gc.collect() then I check with gc.get_objects()